# Entity Framework data seeding DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, datetime

I have the problem, that I only need the date when filling the database. How can I convert the DateTime, that I get only the date out.

[image: Filling Database]
[image: Database]

Comment: Take a look at the [DateTime.Date Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Next time, it would be better write your code as a text, not as an image.

Comment: @SonerGönül ok, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your database, there are several data types for storing dates and times. You are using one that supports both (date and time). I think it's "datetime" or "timestamp". But you need to use a type that stores only the date.

In the data model class of your application, you must specify the type for the field - "DATE".

You can use one of methods:

```
// In model class
[Column(TypeName = "DATE")]
public virtual DateTime DestinationDate {get; set;}

// In model settings
this.modelBuilder.Entity<BusinessTripDocument>(document =>
{
    document.Property(d => d.DestinationDate).HasColumnType("DATE");
}
```

After applying the changes, you will need to make a migration to the database.